# How to Bind Changes From One ListView to Another in Kivy

Tags: python, listview, kivy

What I am trying to achieve is when I click on an entry in *BoxLayoutForEmails* it would change and show appropriate groups in *GroupListView*

I was trying to access the view ***GroupsListView*** through id to get my hands on the adapter instantiated within it dynamically, but to no avail.

So I need either: access the email_address_clicked() somehow or to find another way of doing it.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
class BoxLayoutForEmails(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BoxLayoutForEmails, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        list_adapter = \
            ListAdapter(data=googleEmails,
                        selection_mode='single',
                        propagate_selection_to_data=False,
                        allow_empty_selection=False,
                        cls=ListItemButton)

        list_view = ListView(adapter=list_adapter)

        groups_view = ObjectProperty(None)

        list_adapter.bind(on_selection_change=groups_view.list_adapter.email_address_clicked)
        self.add_widget(list_view)


class GroupsListView(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GroupsListView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.list_adapter = GroupsListAdapter(data=["Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"],
                                              selection_mode='single',
                                              allow_empty_selection=False,
                                              cls=ListItemButton)

        self.list_view = ListView(adapter=self.list_adapter)
        self.list_adapter.bind()
        self.add_widget(self.list_view)

class GroupsListAdapter(ListAdapter):
    def email_address_clicked(self, email_address_adapter, *args):
        if len(email_address_adapter.selection) == 0:
            self.data = []
            return

        email = \
            email_address_adapter.selection[0].text

        if email == "me@mail.com":
            self.data = ["Good Group"]
        else:
            self.data = ["Hm... group"]
```

The kv file:

```
<MainPanel>:
    do_default_tab: False
    my_list: list
    groups_view: view

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Users'
        BoxLayout:
            BoxLayoutForEmails:
            ServicesPanel:
                do_default_tab: False
                TabbedPanelItem:
                    text: 'Google'
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        Label:
                            text: "User Name"
                        GroupsListView:
                            id: view
```

Answer (score 0):

`groups_view` doesn't exist yet in BoxLayoutForEmails constructor, so don't access it's properties directly.  Use a function so it is accessed only after there is a click (it will be created by then):

```
...
list_adapter.bind(on_selection_change=lambda *x: groups_view.list_adapter.email_address_clicked())
...
```

You can use a lambda or a class method.